# Help with nested content_tag in ruby on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using this method in `application_helper.rb` to show the flash. But, I need it to show the content of the flash and the link to make the flash fade away, and I can't seem to do that. All it does right now is show a "close" link.

```
  def show_flash
      [:notice, :error, :alert].collect do |key|
        content_tag(:div, (flash[key] and content_tag(:a, "close", :class => "#{key}", :href => "#", :onclick => "$('messages').fade(); return false;")), :id => key, :class => "flash_#{key}") unless flash[key].blank?
      end.join
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I've come up with. It's not the best, as it wraps the entire flash mesage in an `<a>` tag, but it works well enough.

```
  def show_flash
      [:notice, :errors, :alert].collect do |key|
        msg = (flash[key].to_s + " (click to close)")
        content_tag(:div, (content_tag(:a, msg, :class => "#{key}", :href => "#", :onclick => "$('messages').fade(); return false;")), :id => key, :class => "flash_#{key}") unless flash[key].blank?
      end.join
  end
```